# Class member access : section 3.4.5, point 2: point from N3290 draft C++

Tags: c++, c++11, class-members

Class member access : section 3.4.5, point 2:

> If the id-expression in a class member access (5.2.5) is an
>   unqualified-id, and the type of the object expression is of a class
>   type C, the unqualified-id  is looked up in the scope of class C.
>   **For a pseudo-destructor call (5.2.4),the  unqualified-id is looked
>   up in the context of the complete postfix-expression.**

here in the above statement  : For a pseudo-destructor call (5.2.4),the unqualified-id is looked up in the context of the complete postfix-expression.

can any one explain this in terms of an program (i know about pseudo-destructor call)?

Answer (score 3):

A pseudo-destructor is a destructor-like syntax invoked on a non-class type:

```
typedef int I;
I x;
x.I::~I();
```

If this were parsed “naively”, then the parser would see the following tokens:

unqualified-id(`x`), typename(`I`), `::`, bitwise-negate, typename(`I`), `(`, `)`, `;`.

The “bitwise-negate” is a problem because if you just wrote this:

```
~I();
```

Then this would form a valid expression with a *different* semantic. Namely, the same as `~0`. Therefore, the expression above has to be parsed differently to account for the pseudo-destructor context.

Comment: @user751747 Not sure what you mean. Just put the above code in a `main` function and you’ve got your program.